# If $a_n \in l^2$ then $\sum_{k=1}^n{a_k} = o(\sqrt{n})$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> If $a_n \in l^2$ (ie. $a_n \in \Bbb R^\Bbb N$ and $\sum_{k} a_k^2$ converges) then $\sum_{k=1}^n{a_k} = o(\sqrt{n})$.

I tried Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, I get
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n a_k =O(\sqrt n).
$$
I also tried using $|x| \le x^2 +1$ without success. If $\sum_k a_k$ converges, it's OK. Otherwise, I don't see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $|\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}a_k|\leq |\sum\limits_{k=1}^{N}a_k|+|\sum\limits_{k=N+1}^{n}a_k|$ for $n >N$. Apply  Cauchy-Schwarz inequality for the second term and use the fact that $\sum\limits_{k=N+1}^{\infty}a_k^{2} \to 0$ as $N \to \infty$.

Comment: Thanks! I see now. But why is this trick working? Are we not losing some "distance" by applying the triangle inequality?

Comment: For almost any result invoving Cesaro averages you use this trick. @Michelle